# Cannot set variable to an address unless it is 4-byte aligned

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-alignment

I am using VC++ x86, assume an `int` will be 32-bits and a `short` will be 16 bits.

Lets say I have a variable `short* a;` I want to set it's address to `0xA` Yes I know this will not work when I try to derefence the pointer, and im not actually setting it to such a low address, I'm just simplifying. Although I am hardcoding it to a known value.

`0xA` is not 4-byte aligned so when I do this:

```
short* a = reinterpret_cast<short*>(0xA)
cout << a;
```

I don't get `0xA` I instead get `0x8` which is 2 bytes further down from where I want the variable's address to be. Why does this happen, and how can I set the address of the variable to something that is not 4-byte aligned?

Comment: I can't reproduce your results. Please provide a short, **complete** program that demonstrates the error. See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: this is almost a complete program, minus the main(), and #include <iostream>...

Comment: I agree, it is *almost* a complete program. When I add the `main()` and `#include <iostream>` I don't get the results you do. Please provide a short, complete program, along with the expected and actual output.

Comment: Also, do you literally get `0x8`? Or do you get `0x00000008`?

Comment: What version of VC++ are you using?  This may be important.

Comment: using visual studio 2017 community edition, yes I get a literal `0x8`

Comment: Could not reproduce, I'm getting `0000000A` on VS2015 and [this program's](http://ideone.com/gUOzQY) output is `0xa`. It could depend on various compiler flags.